# Bootstrap3-Angular Form validation error not showing in IE9

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-9

I am using simple form validation on a number field. It is working fine with firefox and chrome but not working with IE9.It is not showing the pop up error message. I am using bootstrap3 and AngularJS.Below is the code:

```
form  class="form-inline"  name="InquiryForm">
             <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{true:'has-error'}[InquiryForm.phNum.$invalid]" >

                      <label for="phNum" >Ph Number</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phNum" id="phNum" maxlength="5">
                      <span data-ng-show="InquiryForm.phNum.$invalid" class="help-inline">Enter a numeric ph number</span>
              </div>        
         <div class="form-group"> 
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
              </div>
        </form>
```

Any help is most appreciated!